# svchost.exe has strange outbound tcp connections

Tags: malware, virus

I installed comodo firewall and svchost.exe has some strange outbound tcp connections. I have turned off the p2p windows update in advanced update settings.
Ip lookup shows connections are to Bangladesh, Mexico, Indonesia, India and one to Hurricane Inc, USA. Now I know for a fact that hurricane inc,fremont is a proxy server. Is my computer infected or is this normal behaviour ?

screenshots of ip lookup :-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6ZDm.jpg

Comment: It's hard to say since you may have plenty of software which can do that. SVCHOST is generic name for service so it's hard to say which software is it.

Comment: One option is to pcap that traffic and verify with an NIDS for example. May be is legitimate traffic or not...

Comment: In Windows 10 svchost is widely used compared to previous Windows versions. There's nothing strange from the information you provided if you're using W10.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after installing Comodo firewall; svchost.exe was establishing multiple outbound connections to the internet.

I tried to block the process, but since it's a system process, I ended up losing the internet.

The solution was to allow UDP and block TCP for the svchost process.

P.S. running Windows 10 64bit